# In Elm, how can I iterate over a map?

Tags: functional-programming, elm

I'm very new to Elm, and to FP in general, but I have a little experience with Haskell. Please forgive me if I'm not using the right terminology here.

I'm trying to do some XSLT-like things, replacing patterns in XML to convert it to HTML.

I have a map of patterns and replacements. I'm not quite sure what the best data structure is for this, but I'm trying something like:

```
type alias Replacement = { pattern: String, replacement: String }

type ReplacementMap = List Replacement

replacementMap : ReplacementMap
replacementMap = [ { pattern: "<head>", replacement: "<h1>" },
                   { pattern: "<lg>", replacement: "<ul>" },
                   { pattern: "<l>", replacement: "<li>" } ]
```

And then I'll do something like:

```
type alias Xml = String

replacePat : Xml -> Html
replacePat pat repl = replace Regex.All (regex pat) (\_ -> repl)
```

to replace the XML tags `head`, `lg`, and `l` with their HTML equivalents.  What I don't know how to do yet is to iterate through my `replacementMap`, replacing each pattern with its replacement. Or maybe there's a better way of doing this entirely?

Comment: You can 'List.map' over your ReplacementMap. Your replacePat function could have a type annotation like 'Xml -> ReplacementMap -> Html'

Comment: I'm having a difficult time imagining how that would work. How would I keep track of how the XML is changing as it iterates through each replacement pair?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, here's a working example:

```
import Html exposing (text)
import Regex as R

type alias Replacement = { pattern: R.Regex, replacement: String }
type alias ReplacementMap = List Replacement
type alias Xml = String

main =
  let
    replacements =
      [ { pattern = R.regex "<head>", replacement = "<h1>" }
      , { pattern = R.regex "</head>", replacement = "</h1>" }
      , { pattern = R.regex "<lg>", replacement = "<ul>" }
      , { pattern = R.regex "</lg>", replacement = "</ul>" }
      , { pattern = R.regex "<l>", replacement = "<li>" }
      , { pattern = R.regex "</l>", replacement = "</li>" }
      ]

    example = "<head>Foo</head>"
  in    
    text (replacePat example replacements)

replace : Replacement -> Xml -> Xml
replace replacement xml =
  R.replace R.All replacement.pattern (always replacement.replacement) xml

replacePat : Xml -> ReplacementMap -> String
replacePat xml rmap =
  List.foldl replace xml rmap
```

To approach the problem first consider your inputs and outputs:

**INPUTS:** a `List` of replacements patterns and a `String` of XML.

**OUTPUTS:** A `String` of HTML

When you have a collection, such as a `List` and you want to get a single thing (ex. a `String`) that's a clue that you'll need to perform some kind of reduction: You're going from many to one. Reducing a `List` usually means you'll be doing a fold (`foldl` or `foldr`).

`foldr` iterates over a list applying the provided function (in this case `replace`) to an item in the list and the previous result of applying the function; Except for the first iteration, during which a starting value is used (the initial XML in your case). This causes a... concatenation effect as the iteration continues. Finally, the result of the last application of the function is returned as the final value.

In otherwords, `List.foldl replace xml rmap` is the same as a bunch of nested function applications (calls):

```
replace 
  { pattern = R.regex "<lg>", replacement = "<ul>" } 
  (replace 
     { pattern = R.regex "</head>", replacement = "</h1>" } 
     (replace 
        { pattern = R.regex "<head>", replacement = "<h1>" }                    
        "<head>Foo</head>"))
```

... and so on.